# What's the absolute maximum damage potential with a melee weapon in dark souls 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

So apparently weapons can do bonus damage according to your stats. The S scaling does the most damage, and then A next, B, C, D, E. That means if you have 99 strength, an S scaling in strength would maximize your damage.
IS there a sword that scales off all the most possible stats? or at least the greatest sum of stats so that their combined damage was the most damage you could get if you were going for a completionist build.

Comment: You may want to specify some details for what you are actually asking for. I would add whether you are looking for most damage in one swing/DPS/backstab/riposte/overall attack damage. The problem with looking for the overall attack damage is that the top contenders will most likely be weapons that have element effects like fire or lightning. They may have the most attack damage but they also have to go through another layer of resistance (physical defence + fire defence for example), so in the end they probably won't do the most possible damage.

Comment: Also, you seem to look at scaling as if it is the main contributing factor to damage. It certainly helps with most weapons but the majority of the damage (in most cases) will come from the base damage of that weapon. You could decide to split your question into what weapon does the most damage in certain circumstances. For example: what weapon does the most backstab/riposte damage, the most damage in one swing, the most DPS, include elemental weapons with different resistances, maybe even effects like poison and bleed that add extra damage and see how it adds up.

Comment: I guess what I was looking for is max possible ar. Attack rating. However weapons like sinner sword have their ar hidden. So I was trying to generalize. So yea what would be the highest possible attack rating weapon in dark souls II? Too bad we didn't figure it out for the 34k people that wanted the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no weapon that has an S scaling in strength *without being upgraded first*, The selection you have to choose from are:

- Red Rust Sword: Upgrades with Twinkling Titanite. At +5 it gains an S scaling in STR.
- King's Ultra Great Sword: Upgrades with Petrified Dragon bone. At +5 it gains an S scaling in STR
- Club: Upgrades with Titanite shard, Large Titanite shards, Chunks and a Slab. At +10 it gets an S Scaling in STR
- Large Club: Upgrades with Titanite shard, Large Titanite shards, Chunks and a Slab. At +10 it gets an S Scaling in STR

**EDIT:** As of 1.08

- Drakekeeper's Ultra Greatsword: Upgrades with Titanite shard, Large Titanite shards, Chunks and a Slab. At +10 it gets an S Scaling in STR
- Greatsword: Upgrades with Titanite shard, Large Titanite shards, Chunks and a Slab. At +10 it gets an S Scaling in STR

The next highest is the Sun Sword which has an A scaling in STR and DEX at +10, followed by the Caestus with an A/B scaling in STR/DEX. The next best is possibly the Curved Dragon Great Sword, which has a B/S scaling in STR/DEX.

As for "Scaling off the most possible stats", the scaling works off your stats, no matter how high they get.

That being said, there are what people call "Soft Levels" in your stats, that are determined by the max amount of levelling a stat gives per level.

For example:

- ~2.3 ATK per level until 30 STR
- 3.8 ATK per level until 40 STR
- 1.5 ATK per level until 50 STR
- ~0.8 DMG per level over 50 STR

So the "Soft Level" for Strength would be level 40, being the maximum return per level up.

Comment: I think the question is asking what is the most damage you can do in the game. Since there is a maximum weapon level and all stats cap at 99 there has to be a weapon in the game that does the "Most" damage isn't there?

Comment: Seeing as the OP asked for strength, I have provided the best option for strength output. that being said, there are weapons that level off different stats, that could possibly do more damage. For example, the Black Knight Halberd has a C scaling in Str, Dex, *and* Faith, allowing for more possible damage output.

Comment: That being said, there are still too many outside factors to determine one single weapon that does "the most damage".

Comment: It seems to me the OP used strength as an example. He goes on to say ' IS there a sword that scales off all the most possible stats? or at least the greatest sum of stats so that their combined damage was the most damage you could get'. Meaning that it seems like he is actually asking what weapon uses the most scaling over all possible stats so that the combined damage could add up to the maximum possible. Of course, there are many variables involved such as the base damage of the weapon. Also there are several weapons with an S rank in strength, the Large Club being one of them when upgraded.

Comment: Something else to think about is if he is looking for damage over time or in one swing. Honestly I think with the current state of the question it cannot be answered without knowing EXACTLY what the OP is asking for. It really goes to show the depth of the equipment system in Dark Souls and it can't simply come down to 'what weapon does the most damage'.

Comment: @SimonM There are a few omissions I need to update, namely some equipment I failed to remember at the time. However I had a similar question that I went into a bit more detail with bows, that explains a bit more about the scaling and such. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177805/what-bow-should-i-use-to-maximize-my-ranged-damage/177840#177840

Comment: @Ben When it comes to maximum damage on Dark Souls there are a lot of things to consider and it can be an awkward question to answer. However, I like your answer as it shows a realistic method of hitting a 'Soft' max with weapon scaling.

Comment: @SimonM indeed it is. Even with the other answer I provided on a similar topic ("which bow does the most damage") I still got a lot of controversial feedback. So I suppose the best you can do is provide the information of what is relevant and hope for the best.

Answer (score -1):

The kings ultra great sword +5 has an S scaling with strength

Comment: also great club or something like that has s scaling in strength. 
I tried dual wielding rules great swords +5 and it doesn't do a lot of damage. So far sythe of want and helix do most.

Answer (score -1):

im pretty certain that the maximum damage would be done with a mundane weapon assuming you have 99 in all stats that is i suppose you can search for the maximum base damage output weapon then infuse it with mundane but im pretty sure the highest base damage melee weapon is the dragon tooth

Comment: When giving an answer of this kind you need to put a bit more effort into it and try your best to back your answers with a link or an information source.